# AMP: <amp-analytics> occasionally does not register click event on Firefox

Tags: firefox, google-analytics, amp-html

For our AMP pages we use `<amp-analytics>` to track outclicks to web shops. This works fine in most browsers, but in Firefox it seems like these outclicks get registered only half of the time (or even less).

I did some research, and in the console I can see that the request (https://www.google-analytics.com/r/collect?...) is not made in the occasions that we do not see any click.

This is our JSON for registering the outclick. When the user clicks on an element with the `.buy-link` class, it should register the outclick in Google Analytics.

```html
<script type="application/json">
  {
    "vars" : {
      "gtag_id": "UA-XXXXXXX",
      "config" : {
        "UA-XXXXXXX": { "groups": "default" }
       }
     },
     "triggers": {
       "button": {
         "selector": ".buy-link",
         "on": "click",
         "vars": {
           "event_name": "NL",
           "event_category": "outclick",
           "method": "Google",
           "event_label" : "${eventLabel}"
         }
       }
     }
  }
</script>
```

The `event-label`'s value is the name of the store that was clicked on. The data for this retrieved from the HTML element that was clicked on:

```html
<a class="buy-link" data-vars-event-label="Store name" href="https://example.com">...</a>
```

The `data-vars-event-label` attribute contains the value for the `event_label`.

Why do the click events get registered only occasionally? Is there maybe something that clashes between AMP and Firefox? I hope someone can answer me.